# Python input validation function (how to get it to run again?)

Tags: python, class, module

Just making an attempt at a simple role-playing game, however I'm in need of some idea on how to get the following code to work properly:

```
from character import demon, knight, skeleton
import fight
import createcharacter
import drawmap


character = createcharacter.makechar()

print """
You are in Shitwick village! Please choose where you want to go:

    * Forest
    * Dungeon
    * Blacksmith

"""
def start():

    choice = raw_input (">")
    wheretogo = ("Forest", "Dungeon", "Blacksmith")


    if choice in wheretogo:

        if choice == "Forest":

            drawmap.createpath("Village","Forest")

            print "You have entered the forest, brave maiden. A demon has attacked you! \n"
            demon = demon()

            fight.battle(character,demon)


        elif choice == "Dungeon":

            drawmap.createpath("Village","Dungeon")
            print "You have entered the dungeon, brave maiden. A skeleton has attack you! \n"
            skeleton = skeleton()

            fight.battle(character,skeleton)

    else:

        print "Please make a valid choice!"
        start()

start()
```

The problem is I'm wanting the **start()** function to complete the input validation, and if the **choice** string does not match anything in the **wheretogo** list, I need the function to re-run from the beginning. The error I get is as follows:

- **local variable demon referenced before assignment**

...the main problem is how to pass those classes **demon() and skeleton()** (from the **character** module) into the **start()** function? I need to find a way to create the **demon()** and **skeleton()** classes on demand, rather than initialise them outside the **start()** function

Comment: You should just use a different name for the class and the instance.  Name your classes `Demon`, `Skeleton`, etc. (using capital letters), then do `demon = Demon()`.

Comment: Oh man, thanks a tonne! What a silly question this turned out to be on my part...here I was beginning to think I couldn't create instances within Python functions. All working now, cheers!